# Making an easter egg, JS action on 5 button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

so I'm attempting to make some sort of easter egg, I've tried multiple different ways with no luck, currently I'm trying to have a button that ill hide some how and when clicked 5 times it hides my page stuff and shows a gif but instead when clicked it automatically hides the page stuff but doesn't show the gif unless its clicked 5 times but you can't click it 5 times because it disappears with the page stuff. anyway here is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var count = 0 ;
        $("button").click(function(){
            count+=1;
            if (count==5)    
                 $( "#datboi" ).toggle();   
                 $( ".body" ).toggle(); 

        });
    });
```

oh and before you link me to the post about action on 5 button click, I've tried it thats how i wrote the stuff above and it doesn't work so yeah

Comment: ajax?? How by JS gods does it have anything to do with ajax? Really no idea why you choose totally wrong tags on purpose like that.

Answer (score 5):

You need braces around your `if` block:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0 ;
    $("button").click(function(){
        count+=1;
        if (count==5) {  
             $( "#datboi" ).toggle();   
             $( ".body" ).toggle(); 
        }

    });
});
```

In javascript, you can omit the braces for an `if` block, but then only the first statement after the conditional is applied to it. So your code is equivalent to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0 ;
    $("button").click(function(){
        count+=1;
        if (count==5) {
             $( "#datboi" ).toggle();   
        }
        $( ".body" ).toggle(); // body is toggled immediately after the first click

    });
});
```

Comment: omfg I'm an idiot thanks